# Using special_price_to_date in shopping cart price rule

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I have a shopping cart price rule that gives 10% discount. This needs to only apply to products without already existing discount (special_price).

Sometimes a product has a 'special_price_to_date'. When this date is in the past, the shopping cart rule should apply. Unfortunatly this is where I run into problems with the rules.

In the image below are the rules currently applied. If someone knows the problem or a solution I'd like to hear it.

[image: action rules for shopping cart price rule]